# Access text selection within a TreeNode (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

Is it possible to access information about the text selection **within** an editable `TreeNode` of a WinForms `TreeView`?

I discovered methods such as `BeginEdit()` and `EndEdit(bool cancel)`, but I need finer granularity of control -- something like `TextBoxBase.SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties, but on the node itself.

Is this possible in C#/.Net?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do some native interop work to get the edit control that is used for the label. To get this control, you need to use the [`TVM_GETEDITCONTROL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773576(VS.85).aspx) message, sending it to the tree view instance in which you want this behavior.

Once you have the window handle from this message, you can then use the [`EM_SETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761661(VS.85).aspx) message on the handle to set the selection.